# What is "herself" or "himself" on IMDB, when you click on filmography of an actress or actor

Tags: meaning, reflexives

What is "herself" or "himself" on the IMDB website, when you click on filmography of an actress or actor?

> Stephen Hawking
>
> **Doctor Who Live: The Next Doctor** (TV Movie)
>   Himself (as Professor Stephen Hawking)
>
> http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0370071/

Answer (score 2):

here is what IMDB [says](http://www.imdb.com/help/search?domain=helpdesk_faq&index=1&file=himself&ref_=hlp_sr_1):
The database lists all kind of titles, not just films. We also list appearances in TV specials, documentaries and other non-fiction productions. The recent surge in popularity of 'making of' featurettes (especially due to the DVD sales boom), reality TV series and other productions where famous (and not-so-famous) people routinely appear as themselves had increased the size of many filmographies to the point where it was hard to tell at a glance which credits were actual movie acting roles.

To reduce the clutter we list some of those credits separately, based on the type of title they appeared in: performances in regular films, TV-series, TV-movies etc. are still listed in the main filmography section; appearances in documentaries, TV-specials (like the Academy Awards ceremony broadcast), making-of featurettes etc are now listed in a separate section called "**Himself**" or "**Herself**", depending on the person's gender.

Comment: In other words, appearances made on one's own behalf, as oneself; i.e., not "playing" any character.